# Security and .ini file

Tags: php, security, ini

Is it safe to store data required to connect to a database in a .ini file ?

I build something like this

```
<?php

    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."proto/class/Database.php"); 

    function connect()
    {
        $config = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."proto/admin/config.ini");   

        $host = $config['host'];
        $username = $config['username'];
        $password = $config['password'];
        $database = $config['dbname'];  

        $db = new Database($host,$username,$password,$database);    
        return $db;
    }

?>
```

I wonder if using important variables within a function is a good way to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save your infos in an ini file or in a php file is a personal thing I guess. What makes it secure is that your file should not be saved in your public web path.
So ensure that the file you read/include is outside of your document root.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask why? Why not make it a PHP file?

```
<?php
return array(
    "host" => "...",
    "username" = "...",
    //...
);
```

Then when you need it, just call `$config = require "config.php";`

This is better than an ini file, since it's parsed (you'll get syntax errors for mistakes rather than ignoring the mistake) and since the parsing is cachable (opcode cache).

Additionally, it's protected from direct web access even if it's in the webroot (or a server misconfiguration allows direct access to the file).